# HtmlElement SetAttribute property fails

Tags: c#, html, silverlight

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = HtmlPage.Document;
HtmlElement htmlEl;

htmlEl = htmlDoc.GetElementById("UserText");
htmlEl.SetAttribute("scrollHeight", "400");
```

gives me exception `SetAttribute  Operation failed`

Any ideas or workaround on this?

Comment: This does not look like JavaScript although you tagged it as such. What programming language and framework are you using?

Comment: C#
this is silverlight application.

Comment: It looks like client-side code - where does this exception appear?

Comment: I was playing with readonly property. window.dialogHeight = size+"px";  works.

Comment: is there any method to increase window height from bottom?